# AWS S3 SDK source code is showing completeMultipartUpload() with UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java-2.0, unsupportedoperation

I am trying to use AWS S3 SDK 2.13 and seeing the completeMultipartUpload method is implemented like this in their source code -

```
default CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeMultipartUpload(CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeMultipartUploadRequest)
   throws AwsServiceException, SdkClientException, S3Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

I am surprised to see that such obvious apis are not implemented in s3 sdk 2+ versions but their documentation shows usage of it -
https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/master/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3ObjectOperations.java#L210
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html

I even tried downloading and seeing the source code in decompiler for 2.14 version and it's the same -
[decompiler s3 sdk code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6fHZ.png)

I am not sure whether I am looking at it right because it's vey unlikely that AWS is missing such widely used functionality in most of their recent versions.

note- I am importing aws sdk s3 dependency using sbt -

```
"software.amazon.awssdk" % "s3" % "2.13.8"
```

Comment: Note [features not yet available in Java SDK 2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/welcome.html#features-notyet).

Comment: Thank for reply @jarmod. But above note mentions high level API TransferManager not being available yet. Low level API should be available. at least all examples point to low level api similar to older version - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpListPartsJavaAPI.html